# PHP - Anything after ASCII char being dropped at file_get_contents()

Tags: php, ascii

I am trying to upload a CSV and save its contents in the database for processing later. The CSV file happens to have an ASCII character at a certain place. This is on of the cells in the CSV

```
inflatable?ÿtavel?ÿpillow
```

Now when try to read this file into the database using PHP (cakePHP to be precise), `file_get_contents()` ignores everything after the first `ÿ`

```
$fh = fopen($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'], 'rb');            
$this->request->data['ChannelUpload']['data'] = file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: That's precisely ***not*** an "ASCII character", it's a *non-ASCII character*. And how are you confirming that `file_get_contents` is dropping the data? It has the least to do with it probably.

Comment: Does `echo file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name']);` have the same issue, or does it read the entire file fine?

Comment: Also, why `fopen` + `file_get_contents`?

Comment: Also, shouldn't you be using Cake's file upload handling infrastructure?

Answer (score -1):

Check on php.net:

```
  <?php
    function file_get_contents_utf8($fn) {
         $content = file_get_contents($fn);
          return mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8',
              mb_detect_encoding($content, 'UTF-8, ISO-8859-1', true));
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: Nobody said anything about this *not* being UTF-8, so what are you proposing random encoding conversions for?